# Installed application doesn't have write permissions anywhere

Tags: c#, permissions, wix, installation

I have created a C# application, not having in mind that all debugging were done using administrator rights as I always use in Windows.

Now that I have installed my application by using WiX to create an .MSI installer, the application doesn't have write permissions to either appdata, C:\tmp or the like.

My application needs to write some temporary files somewhere on the filesystem, how can I achieve this without needing admin rights for my application? The application doesn't do anything that should require administator elevation.

Comment: What are the exact paths you're writing to? You can only write to per-user directories.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx), maybe?

Comment: @slaks %appdata%\myApp (created by wix with permissions), c:\temp, mydocs...

Comment: @lemon42 by temporary files I meant text files that will be created with some custom content before execution of a specific task and deleted after execution. Can I still use your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only needed a temporary file to read and write from, I was able to use the Windows API to get a temp-file for my application

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

Now I could write and read to the path of `tempFile` at will. Noted that this file is deleted upon exit and a new one is created for each call to `Path.GetTempFileName()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. It should always be accessible to your application.

You could try obtaining the temp directory with `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`.

If that doesn't work, you could try finding a non-system partition and creating a hidden folder there.

Comment: As said in question, I don't have access there either :S

Comment: You could try finding the temp folder or creating a hidden folder on a different partition.

Comment: That is just wrong I think, creating folders without the users knowledge.